# Mysqli column shortening

Tags: loops, mysqli, varchar

I just uploaded my game and it was working great in Wamp. Now, when I run it on the main website it shortens "names" of rows in tables to just be the first letter?

The code is simple to do it

```
$id = 0;
$stmt->prepare("SELECT name,id FROM `users` WHERE id > ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i',$id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($name,$id);
while($r = $stmt->fetch()) {
echo $id." : ".$name."<br>";
}
```

It outputs
1 : A
2 : A
3 : n
4 : T
5 : R
6 : M
7 : R

***EDIT***

I figured it out!

```
$stmt->store_result();
```

Needs to go after

```
$stmt->execute();
```

If you plan to fetch the row. Hope this helps someone.

***EDIT***

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at the type of that column in your database?

Comment: It's varchar. If i do a one row pull, it outputs the entire name.

Comment: You are actually using `$name` and not something like `$name[0]`, right?

Comment: Instead of just editing you question, you should write up an answer yourself and accept it. It's just the way this place works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

```
stmt->store_result();
```

Needs to go after

```
$stmt->execute();
```

If you plan to fetch the row. Hope this helps someone.